# Sqlite> not showing up in Git Bash terminal

Tags: database, windows, bash, sqlite, cmd

[Where is the sqlite> tag on Git Bash so I know when I'm accessing sqlite? There's also no version text too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWfJz.png)

[When I enter .quit into git bash it quits out of sqlite (showing that I am accessing sqlite) but there's no tag like there is in cmd or powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aqjq.png)

[On the cmd terminal when I access Sqlite3 it clearly shows sqlite> so I know when I'm in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGcfQ.png)

How do I get the sqlite> tag on Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

Things like these make use of interactive terminals, and MinTTY (the underlying emulator used to run Git Bash) doesn't get along well with them. You need to prefix every such command with `winpty`. In this case: `winpty sqlite3`.